# Contents, list of figures and list of tables

Tags: table-of-contents, xetex

In my contents, list of figures and list of tables, the enumeration of the sections and the listed things appear superimposed.

[image: MWE image]

```
% Format table of contents
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{5mm}
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for parts
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for chapters
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for sections
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for subsections
\renewcommand{\cftfigleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for figures
\renewcommand{\cfttableader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for tables
```

Comment: Please provide the community with a minimal document that replicates this problematic behaviour. Something that has just two `\section`s, say, that overlap in the ToC. It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` and allow us to copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you're seeing. Can you do that?

Comment: No need to `renew...` the `sec`, `subsec`, `fig` and `tab` leaders as those are their default specifications.